# How to add a datepicker and edit inline in jqGrid in MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

**This is the jqGrid script. I want to insert a datepicker in "targetdate" field and I can't edit inline, I would like to edit inline.**

```js
$(function () {
    $("#grid").jqGrid({
        url: "/TodoList/GetTodoLists",
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'Get',
        colNames: ['Id', 'Task Name', 'Task Description', 'Target Date', 'Severity', 'Task Status'],
        colModel: [
            { key: true, hidden: true, name: 'Id', index: 'Id', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'TaskName', index: 'TaskName', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'TaskDescription', index: 'TaskDescription', editable: true },
            //{ key: false, name: 'TargetDate', index: 'TargetDate', editable: true, editoptions: { dataInit: function (el) { setTimeout(function () { $(el).datepicker(); }, 200); } }, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'd/m/Y' } },
            {
                key: false, name: 'TargetDate', index: 'TargetDate', editable: true,
                editoptions: {
                    dataInit: function (el)
                    { setTimeout(function () { $(el).datepicker(); }, 200); }
                }
            },
            { key: false, name: 'Severity', index: 'Severity', editable: true, edittype: 'select', editoptions: { value: { 'L': 'Low', 'M': 'Medium', 'H': 'High' } } },
            { key: false, name: 'TaskStatus', index: 'TaskStatus', editable: true, edittype: 'select', editoptions: { value: { 'A': 'Active', 'I': 'InActive' } } }],
        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40],
        height: '100%',
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: 'Todo List',
        loadonce: false,
        cellEdit: true,
        emptyrecords: 'No records to display',
        jsonReader: {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false,
            Id: "0"
        },
        autowidth: true,
        multiselect: false,
        onSelectRow: function (id) {
            //if (id && id !== lastsel) {
            //    jQuery('#list').jqGrid('saveRow', lastsel);
            //    jQuery('#list').jqGrid('editRow', id, true);
            //    lastsel = id;
            //}
        }
    }).navGrid('inlineNav', '#pager', { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: true, refresh: true },
        {
            // edit options
            zIndex: 100,
            url: '/TodoList/Edit',
            closeOnEscape: true,
            closeAfterEdit: true,
            recreateForm: true,
            viewPagerButtons: false,
            width: 600,
            afterComplete: function (response) {
                if (response.responseText) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            }
        },
        {
            // add options
            zIndex: 100,
            url: "/TodoList/Create",
            closeOnEscape: true,
            width: 600,
            closeAfterAdd: true,
            afterComplete: function (response) {
                if (response.responseText) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            }
        },
        {
            // delete options
            zIndex: 100,
            url: "/TodoList/Delete",
            closeOnEscape: true,
            closeAfterDelete: true,
            recreateForm: true,
            msg: "Are you sure you want to delete this task?",
            afterComplete: function (response) {
                if (response.responseText) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            }
        });
    $('#filterButton').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        filterGrid();
    });

    //$('#TargetDate').datepicker({
    //    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
    //});
});
```

Style file and JS file:

```html
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/dd.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/TodoList.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dd.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-en.js"></script>
```

**If anyone can suggest the perfect style and js file for datepicker, It will be a great help.**
Thanks

Comment: Can you please fiddle your code?

Comment: Yeah please fiddle your code with local data,It would makes it easier to answer.

Comment: Can u please give me the CSS, JS and IMAGE file for datepicker?

Comment: As you are already using JQueryUI you can use datepicker of JQueryUI  .Try this link http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply initiate `.datepicker` of jQuery to each textbox of jqGrid

```
 editoptions:{size:20, 
                  dataInit:function(el){ 
                        $(el).datepicker({dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy'}); 
                  },
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CzVVK/1470/)